# How to set rounded corner for Uiimageview in Collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make a `UICollectionviewCell` as per the following design

[image]

I have set corner radius for the cell, but when data is loaded on the `collectonview` the `imageview` is not getting rounded corners. The output that i am getting is as follows

[image]

Rounded corners are getting applied to the cells but not to the images. Here is the code that i am applying. The code is applied on `collectionView`(`_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()

cell.layer.cornerRadius      = 15

cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

cell.layer.masksToBounds     = true
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include relevant code to be considered on-topic on SO. See [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the relevant code in your question. Are you sure you set up both corner radius and `clipsToBounds = true` for the `UIImageView` as well and not just for the collection view cell?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `imageView layer corner` radius:-

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I dont want to set corner radius to the imageView. The corner radius is to be set to the cell only.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

This is if you want to add a nice shadow to the background:

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0,height: 2.0)
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false;
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cell.bounds, cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Answer (score 1):

You could say: `cell.clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "user defined run time attribute" to set the corner radius to your imageview
Keypath - layer.cornerRadius
Type - number
Value - your corner radius value

Comment: I dont want to set corner radius to the imageView. The corner radius is to be set to the cell only.